# How can I access images in sibling folder PHP

Tags: php

I have to display targetImage.png on index.php, Thanks in advance!
This is my setup:

```
public_html
    >mobile
        >>index.php
    >web
        >>images/
            >>>targetImage.png
```

Comment: /web/images should retrieve the image !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard `<img>` element on your page should do the trick...

```
<img src="../web/images/targetImage.png">
```

That is using a relative path.  You could also use

```
<img src="http://www.zzz.com/web/images/targetImage.png">
```

which is an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but what should I replace ".." with?

Comment: Nothing...you need that to go up a directory before going into web/images.

Answer (score 2):

"../web/images/targetImage.png"